# Autoserve media files sequentially for Quarto Website, using R

Tags: r, quarto

I am using R to render several Quarto websites for a volunteer project, on a local network.  Several of these sites or pages include media (mostly mp3).  I am able to allow "click to play" and works fine.  My limit is, for certain pages, I would like to sequentially auto start the next media file after the one that is selected ends.  It is OK to stop after the list is completed (does not need to auto loop).  If auto loop is possible, I may be interested in that in the future. I believe there is an HTML5 solution for this, but I am not a professional coder and this lies beyond my experience.

I am expecting that regardless of media type the solution is the same, but do not want to assume that.  I would like the ability to auto server mp4 or other media in the future.

I use R version 4.1.2 ,   Rstudio - 2023.06.1 Build 524, on a Linux machine with POP OS.

Thank you
Robert